# jquery click not working after confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I´ve a strange problem. I am providing a link which sends an ajax request to delete a user. If the User clicks a link for the first time and confirms the confirm box the ajax function is triggered. but if the user after that again clicks a link with class delUser, nothing happens. No confirm Box nothing, It seems the click function is ignored than. I found out if I cut the part with the confirmbox everything works fine.

Whats wrong with this confirm?

```
jQuery(".delUser").click(function(){       
    // open confirm Window
    confirm = window.confirm("Nutzer wirklich löschen?");
    User = $(this).attr("data-link");

    if(confirm == true){

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Admin/DelUser.php",
            data: { where: User },
            success: function(retData){
                    jQuery.noticeAdd({text: "" + retData + "",
                    stay: false, 
                    type: 'error'
                });                             
                }
            }); 
            $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 

            } else {
                   talk("Nutzer wurde nicht gelöscht");
            }         
    });
```

Kind regards,

Tony

Comment: Change the name of the confirm variable first and make it something like var doOperation = window.confirm. it is happening due to conflict for confirm. use var to define any new variable to avoid its global scope.

Comment: Don't forget to declare the User variable, too :) `var User = ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are overwriting `confirm`.

This line:

```
confirm = window.confirm("Nutzer wirklich löschen?");
```

is equal to

```
window.confirm = window.confirm("Nutzer wirklich löschen?");
```

One of the reasons why [using globals is a very bad idea](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/). When you are [declaring a variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Declaring_variables), please always use `var`, so it will not be global:

```
var confirm = window.confirm("Nutzer wirklich löschen?");
```

The same would apply to `User`. You should declare it like:

```
var User = $(this).attr("data-link");
```

Comment: wow this was fast!, means because i do confirm = ... its not working?

Comment: perfect, this realy opened my eyes! thanks to you + everybody who answered. t

Comment: @tBook Happy I could help. One less people using globals was already worth it :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(".delUser").click(function(){       
User = $(this).attr("data-link");

if(window.confirm("Nutzer wirklich löschen?")){

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/DelUser.php",
        data: { where: User },
        success: function(retData){
                jQuery.noticeAdd({text: "" + retData + "",
                stay: false, 
                type: 'error'
            });                             
            }
        }); 
        $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 

        } else {
               talk("Nutzer wurde nicht gelöscht");
        }         
});
```